# Relative self links

Tags: google-sheets

I need to create a relative link (eg `#gid=0&range=B10`) to the doc/sheet itself.

What are some solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the HYPERLINK function. For example:

```
=HYPERLINK("#rangeid=1301150497","Holdings!M8")
```

You can refer to named ranges or cells, in addition to external content. Use Insert -> Link menu to access the link function.

Comment: are there other solutions that are more "scripting"?

Comment: What do you mean by scripting?

Answer (score -2):

I use the formula 'SheetName'!E73